# Tomcat 7- no puedo ampliar "maximum memory pool"

Tags: tomcat

Tengo un `Tomcat 7` con las características de memoria que tiene la imagen que adjunto.Tenemos un problema de "Permgen Space". He intentado ampliar `"maximum memory pool"` pero si pongo mas de 1536 no arranca. El servidor tiene 3GB de memoria pero hasta hace unos días tenía 2GB y el problema era el mismo.
¿Como soluciono el problema de `PermGen Space` si no puedo darle mas memoria?
¿Como puedo dar mas de 1536MB?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y gracias.
Rob

Comment: Buenas, en vez de poner la imagen ponlo en texto, pues si la imagen deja de estar disponible, la pregunta deja de estar completa.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar lo siguiente:

Abre o crea el fichero setenv.bat en el directorio `bin` dentro de Tomcat y añade algo similar a

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

En general te aconsejo configurar Tomcat mediante los archivos de configuración.